# EXCEL Macro to open XML files as a XML table rather than a read only workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to open multiple xml files, however they are opening as a read only workbook, however I require it to open as an XML table, any suggestions?

**Code:**

```
Sub AllFolderFiles()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim TheFile As String
    Dim MyPath As String
    MyPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\"
    ChDir MyPath
    TheFile = Dir("*.xml")
    Do While TheFile <> ""
        'Call Logs 'This calls for Macro2 to run
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & "\" & TheFile)
        MsgBox wb.FullName
        'wb.Close
        TheFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub AllFolderFiles() Dim wb As Workbook Dim TheFile As String Dim MyPath As String MyPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\anpuntam2fae\Desktop\Cilat_devp_Anand P" ChDir MyPath TheFile = Dir("*.xml") Do While TheFile <> "" 'Call Logs 'This calls for Macro2 to run Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & "\" & TheFile) MsgBox wb.FullName 'wb.Close TheFile = Dir Loop End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Workbooks.OpenXML` instead

`Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=MyPath & "\" & TheFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)`

I'm not exactly which LoadOption you want to use, but you can choose from:

- `xlXmlLoadImportToList` Automatically creates an XML List and imports
  data into the list.
- `xlXmlLoadMapXml` Loads the XML file into the XML    Source task pane.
- `xlXmlLoadOpenXml` Open XML files in the same way    that Excel 2002
  opens XML files (for backwards compatibility only).
- `xlXmlLoadPromptUser` Prompts the user and lets them choose the Import 
  method.

Comment: Thanks for the help nick, it worked , however the name of the files which opend were in the order of Book1, book2, book3, is there a way by which the name can be retained ?

Comment: sorry @user1966602 I'm not actually sure

Comment: I usesd the following peice of code, to find and replace which was much simpler